# Warning: [react-router] Location"" did not match any routes

Tags: reactjs, react-router, flux

I am French , I speak little English I'm sorry.

I have a similar problem. I am trying to make a film site with OMDB API. I want to view the details of a film on another page.

I have this error message : "Warning: [react-router] Location "Batman Begins" did not match any routes"

App.js :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { Router, Route, Link, IndexRoute, hashHistory, browserHistory } from 'react-router';

var Routes = require('./Routes.js');

var App = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return(
            <div>
                <Routes />
            </div>
        )
    }
});

module.exports = App;
```

Routes.js :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { Router, Route, Link, IndexRoute, hashHistory, browserHistory } from 'react-router'
var Home = require('./Home.js');
var Contact = require('./Contact.js');
var Search = require('./Search.js');
var NotFound = require('./NotFound.js');
var Details = require('./Details.js');

var Routes = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return(
        <Router history={browserHistory}>
            <Route path='/' component={Home} />
            <Route path='contact' component={Contact} />
            <Route path='search' component={Search}>
                <Route path=":title" handler={require('./Details.js')}/>
            </Route>
        </Router>
    )
  }
});

module.exports = Routes;
```

Movie.js :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { Router, Route, Link, IndexRoute, hashHistory, browserHistory } from 'react-router'
var AppActions = require('../actions/AppActions');
var AppStore = require ('../stores/AppStore');
var Details = require ('./Details');

var Movie = React.createClass({


    render: function(){
        var link = 'http://www.imdb.com/title/' + this.props.movie.imdbID;

        return(
            <div className="well">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-md-4">
                        <img className="thumbnail" src={this.props.movie.Poster} /> 
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-8">
                        <h4><Link to={this.props.movie.Title} activeClassName="current">{this.props.movie.Title}</Link></h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>    
        )
    },
});

module.exports = Movie;
```

Details.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { Router, Route, Link, IndexRoute, hashHistory, browserHistory } from 'react-router'
var AppActions = require('../actions/AppActions');
var AppStore = require ('../stores/AppStore');

// initialisation de la vue 
var Details = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        var link = 'http://www.imdb.com/title/' + this.props.movie.imdbID;

        return(
            <div className="well">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-md-4">
                        <img className="thumbnail" src={this.props.movie.Poster} /> 
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-8">
                        <h4><a href={this.props.movie.Title}> { this.props.movie.Title}</a></h4>
                        <ul className="padding">
                            <li className="list-group-item">Type : {this.props.movie.Type}</li>
                            <li className="list-group-item">Year Released : {this.props.movie.Year}</li>
                            <li className="list-group-item">Id imdb : {this.props.movie.imdbID}</li>
                        </ul>
                        <a className="btn btn-primary" href={link}>View on IMDB</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>    
        )
    },
});

// Renvoie à App.js
module.exports = Details;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe change this line:

```
<h4><Link to={this.props.movie.Title} activeClassName="current">{this.props.movie.Title}</Link></h4>
```

to:

```
<h4><Link to={link} activeClassName="current">{this.props.movie.Title}</Link></h4>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. It shows me the ID in the URL and puts me this error message : bundle.js:28479 Warning: A path must be pathname + search + hash only, not a fully qualified URL like "http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0372784"

Answer (score 0):

In your Movies.js file, change this

```
<h4><Link to={this.props.movie.Title} activeClassName="current">{this.props.movie.Title}</Link></h4>
```

to

```
<h4><Link to={'search/' + this.props.movie.Title} activeClassName="current">{this.props.movie.Title}</Link></h4>
```

Because your Details.js is a child route of Search